# Logrotate permission denied

Tags: linux, logrotate

I have a custom logrotate configuration like:

```
/var/log/myapp-*log {
    daily
    rotate 7
    missingok
    notifempty
    su www-data www-data
}
```

And when I run:

```
sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/myconf --verbose -f
```

it produces the error:

```
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.7 to /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.8 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 7), 
old log /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.7 does not exist
renaming /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.6 to /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.7 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 6), 
old log /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.6 does not exist
renaming /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.5 to /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.6 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 5), 
old log /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.5 does not exist
renaming /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.4 to /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.5 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 4), 
old log /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.4 does not exist
renaming /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.3 to /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.4 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 3), 
old log /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.3 does not exist
renaming /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.2 to /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.3 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 2), 
old log /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.2 does not exist
renaming /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.1 to /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.2 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.1 does not exist
renaming /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.0 to /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.1 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.0 does not exist
log /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.8 doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /var/log/myapp-stdout.log to /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.1
error: failed to rename /var/log/myapp-stdout.log to /var/log/myapp-stdout.log.1: Permission denied
```

Why is `sudo` getting a permission denied error?

Running `ls -lah /var | grep -i log` shows me:

```
drwxrwxr-x 21 root     syslog    56K Oct 16 13:24 log
```

So root owns `/log`. Therefore shouldn't `sudo logrotate` have no problem renaming log files there?

Comment: Are you using MAC? (i.e. SELinux or apparmor)

Answer (score 0):

The problem my logrotate's `su` setting, which should have been `root syslog`.